# AASTEX-like package that's compatible with numeric reference format?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, aastex

I like the [aastex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/aastex) package for its formatting defaults (and a few other things), but it's not consistent with numeric reference format (i.e. [1](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/aastex), [2], ...). Does anyone know of a package like aastex that can work with numeric references?

I've tried adding `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` since I think aastex includes that package. I got an error message telling me to try adding `numbers` to the options list for the class. I can get numbers in the text, though it uses parentheses rather than brackets and the numbers don't appear in the bibliography.

I've used packages for conference proceedings that do work, but they tend to have very large margins, headers, etc. and are missing other features of aastex.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I can see, the current version of `aastex` doesn't enforce a bibliographic style. Do `\documentclass{aastex631}`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem. My solution was to slightly modify the aastex.cls style file by commenting out the following three lines, like so:

```
% \RequirePackage{natbib}%
% \newcommand{\bibstyle@aas}{\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{,}}
% \@citestyle{aas}
```

Then in the preamble of my .tex file, I have:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{aastex2}  % <-- I renamed the modified file "aastex2.cls"
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[aastex,preprint]{aastex631}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\citep{author1,author2}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{your_bib_file}
\end{document}
```

Comment: IMHO It would be friendly to refer to egreg's comment. And it would be helpful to quote it.